# if search string matched, than read only specific word from line in powershell

Tags: powershell

First, an appology for asking very simple question as i am completely new in powershell.

i have file like:

```
"your>desired>output" START:  this is th
e output
next line
next line
"your>desired>output" START:  this is th
e output
```

my task is if "desired" word is found, than read only "output" and than 
"this is the output"

if i use

```
Select-String *.txt -pattern "desired"
```

than the output is

```
"your>desired>output" START:  this is th
```

"e output" is missing .

Any kind of help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: `Select-String *.txt "desired" -Context 1|%{ $_.Line; $_.Context.PostContext}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Checking for a dupe regarding context but you might as well make that the answer (with a little explanation of course)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks for response but this is not returning anything ...... :( indded it shows an error, i use extra -pattern before "desired"

Comment: It might not be perfectly clear how you determine what lines you need after the match. However if you are just looking to match the lines following the match then the answer you have hear as well as the dup should cover it.

Comment: @Matt i just want the next one line contain "e output" because this is the message of previous line

Comment: Have you tried to use something like Get-Content -Path "Your/File/Path/*.txt" | Where { $_ -icontains "desired" }

Comment: Then you should have what you are looking for between the two answers. The one here as well as the duplicate post.

Comment: @PatrickMcvay That logic is flawed. `-contains` is an array operator not a string one. Also the op only wants the one line after the match. -Context should be better for that.

Comment: @Matt only the next line, not the previous one but your given link answer gives also the previous line.

Comment: @user6633897 I should hope that you can apply the logic shown in that answer to your own question. Context is what you want. That answer is still useful even though it is not copy and paste what you need.

Comment: if i use -Context 0,1, than it gives the next line but a new line is entered, i dont want that extra word @Matt

Comment: Try this .....  Get-Help Select-String -Examples .... there are actually a few in there that should help you, and if you are completely new to powershell there are some really good courses on MVA.

Comment: @PatrickMcvay thanks for help ... will look up to this

Answer (score 2):

If you want x lines preceding or following a match, you can use the `-Context` parameter.

Simply indicate how many lines you want from before and after the match, like so:

```
Select-String $path $pattern -Context 1
```

This will give us 1 line before and 1 line after each match. You can access these lines through the `Context` property of the resulting `MatchInfo` object:

```
Select-String *.txt "desired" -Context 1 |ForEach-Object {
    # Output the matched line
    $_.Line
    # And then the next line
    $_.Context.PostContext
}
```

Comment: thanks again but it is not giving the proper result ...... :(